# Equivalent mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this:

```
$rs = mysql_query('select zip  from _zipcode where zip like "'.$consulta .'%"');
```

How I can convert the code above to `mysqli`?

I tried something like this, but is not completed

```
($sql = $db -> prepare('select zip from _zipcode where zip // ));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($sql = $db->prepare('select zip from _zipcode where zip like ?'))
{
    $sql->bind_param("s", $consulta);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($zip);

    while ($sql->fetch()) {
        echo "Zip: $zip\n";
    }

    $sql->close();
}
```

All based off of http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: i think that is not directly equivalent

Comment: Umm... I started with the CODE YOU WROTE.

Answer (score -1):

**Your Line:**

```
     $rs = mysql_query('select zip  from _zipcode where zip like "'.$consulta .'%"');
```

**SQLi Line:**

```
        $query="select zip  from _zipcode where zip like " .$consulta . "%";
        $rs = mysqli_query($connection_information,$query) or  die(mysqli_error($connection_information));
       $row_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
       $totalRows_rs = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

    do {  
        echo $row_rs['zip'];

        } while ($row_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs));
          $rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
          if($rows > 0) {
           mysqli_data_seek($rs, 0);
           $row_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
                          }
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)